# Run commands on create a new Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to add instructions like `RUN` in `Dockerfile` that, instead of run on `docker build` command, execute when a new container is created with `docker run`? I think this can be useful to initialize a volume attached to host file system.

Comment: FYI – A new container may be created with `docker run`, but it can also be created with `docker create`. AFAIK there is no command that can be run when just `docker create` is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint) command.  This specifies a command to run when the container starts, regardless of what someone provides as a command on the `docker run` command line.  In fact, it is the job of the `ENTRYPOINT` script to interpret any command passed to `docker run`.

Comment: An `ENTRYPOINT` script will run on `docker start`, but you could easily include logic in the script such that it could check if it had previously run.

Comment: Although I don't think this is a good way to do this, it's a Docker problem. The `ENTRYPOINT` seems to be a proper workaround.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for the `CMD`

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd

> The main purpose of a `CMD` is to provide defaults for an executing
>   container. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit
>   the executable, in which case you must specify an `ENTRYPOINT`
>   instruction as well.
>
> **Note:** don't confuse `RUN` with `CMD`. `RUN` actually runs a command and
>   commits the result; `CMD` does not execute anything at build time, but
>   specifies the intended command for the image.

You should also look into using Data Containers see this excellent Blog post.

**Persistent volumes with Docker - Data-only container pattern**
http://container42.com/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/

Comment: There is a downside using `CMD`: a `Dockerfile` can have many of it, but only the last one will run.