# Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded in circleci/mysql

Tags: mysql, circleci, circleci-2.0, mysql-8.0

I've recently encountered problems when testing code in CircleCi 2.
Parts of our config.yml:

```
jobs:
  build:
    environment:
    docker:
      ...
      - image: circleci/mysql
      - image: rabbitmq:3-alpine
    working_directory: ~/webapp

    steps:
      ...
      - run:
          name: Prepare DB
          command: echo "create database" | mysql --host 127.0.0.1
```

The build fails at `Prepare DB` with

`ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Error loading shared library /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: No such file or directory
Exited with code 1`

This error only occurred now, and no changes has been made to the circle / mysql setup.

From e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944625/2713641 it is specified that one can set a `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` flag but not sure if that applies here, or how to apply it in a circle ci setup.

Comment: Added the mysql 8.0 tag because this question is mysql 8.0 related

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as here: [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is mysql 8 specific (as pointed out by Raymond), and the error occured due to CircleCi upgrading their latest docker image to mysql 8. Therefore, the solution to our specific case (we are using mysql 5.7) was simply to specify the appropriate tag for the mysql docker image:

```
jobs:
  build:
    environment:
    docker:
      ...
      - image: circleci/mysql:5.7
```

Comment: Some people use mysql 8 for a reason and their setups are not backwards compatible with mysql 5.7. In this case @Yannick's answer is better

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep mysql 8, configure it this way

```
- image: circleci/mysql:latest
  # just add this:
  command: [--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password]
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp_test
```

Source : https://discuss.circleci.com/t/solved-mysql-8-0-without-mysql2-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded/25791