# A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source error when try to connect docker mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, docker, orm

,

I am trying to use docker mysql with a hibernate application. 
my db.properties is :

```
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=pass
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:3306/keystone?autoReconnect=true
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

where **docker container ip (172.17.0.2)** is used.

my hibernate configuration is:

> ```
>     <property name="show_sql">false</property>
>     <property name="format_sql">true</property>
>     <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
>     <property name="generate_statistics">false</property>
>     <property name="max_fetch_depth">2</property>
>     <property name="default_batch_fetch_size">16</property>
>     <property name="use_streams_for_binary">true</property>
>     <property name="connection.isolation">2</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
>
>     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">300</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
>
> </session-factory>
> ```

**I can access docker mysql with any client** but when I try to connect from my application , I am getting this error:

```
 <exception name="Could not open connection">
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
    at org.jpos.ee.DB.beginTransaction(DB.java:168)
    at com.bkash.keystone.participant.AbstractParticipant.openDB(AbstractParticipant.java:91)
    at com.bkash.keystone.participant.AbstractParticipant.createTrace(AbstractParticipant.java:150)
    at com.bkash.keystone.participant.AbstractParticipant.traceDb(AbstractParticipant.java:144)
    at com.bkash.keystone.participant.AbstractParticipant.log(AbstractParticipant.java:124)
    at com.bkash.keystone.participant.AbstractParticipant.prepare(AbstractParticipant.java:68)
    at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.prepare(TransactionManager.java:571)
    at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.prepare(TransactionManager.java:637)
    at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.run(TransactionManager.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:689)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    ... 18 more
    </exception>
```

Hibernate failed to get a connection from mysql connection pool. Don't know why.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution of this problem.I have used this below command.

> sudo docker run --name keystone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e
>   MYSQL_DATABASE=keystone -d mysql:latest

which installed the **mysql verison 8.0.11** and Authentication Type 
**'caching_sha2_password'** was the problem. 
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979089/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded-in-circleci-mysql) helps me a lot.

I have created the container with this below command (**mysql:5.7)**

> sudo docker run --name keystone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e
>   MYSQL_DATABASE=keystone -d mysql:5.7

Which allow me to create a user with **standard authentication type**.

N.B Don't forget to add required **Administrative Roles**  and **Schema  Privileged**