# Why can't I connect to my MySQL database using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I can't connect to my MySQL database using MySQL Workbench. I'm using **MySQL Community Server 8.0.11** and **MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE**. I'm also using Windows 10 Home.

When I click in the default MySQL connection in MySQL Workbench it says it has encountered an error. No more information is provided.
[image: Screenshot of the error]

I am able to connect to my MySQL Server without any problem using the command
`mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`.

Following is the status of my server.

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          12
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 15 min 55 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 6  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 110  Flush tables: 2  Open tables: 86  Queries per second avg: 0.006
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I executed MySQL Workbench using -log-level=debug3 command: `MySQLWorkbench.exe -log-level=debug3`.

After reading the log generated by the program I found following information:

```
21:10:22 [ERR][SQL Editor Form]: SqlEditorForm: exception in do_connect method: Exception: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

21:10:22 [ERR][  GRTDispatcher]: exception in grt execute_task, continuing: Exception: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

21:10:22 [ERR][  GRTDispatcher]: worker: task 'execute sql queries' has failed with error:.Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

21:10:22 [ERR][SQL Editor Form]: SQL editor could not be connected: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

21:10:22 [ERR][SQL Editor Form]: Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

This question [Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded) helped me resolving the problem. Now I can connect to my MySQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is **MySQL Workbench** that's not starting correctly on your machine. I found [**this**](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70546) from the official website try and see if it works if not try reporting the bug to the dev team and wait for a response. Alternatively you can try using a different tool to connect to your database.

Comment: Thank you. The link you passed to me led me to discover that caching_sha2_password is the cause of the problem.