# MySQL server connection is failing

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Whenever I try to connect to MySQL database I get this message, despite the fact that it logs in properly from the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Seems you're missing a dynamic library for your authentication. Maybe also the workbench has not all dependencies installed.

Comment: We can not guess where the problem is coming from from your description.

Comment: Please search SO first before you post your question. This [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826727/mysql-8-0-11-error-connecting-due-to-caching-sha2-password/50830407) several times before.

Comment: Check mysql service is running.