# MySQL server-8 not connecting with SQLyog-13

Tags: mysql, sqlyog, mysql-8.0

I installed mysql-8.0.11-winx64 and SQLyog-13.0.1-0.x64Community in my Windows-10 laptop. When trying to connect SQLyog with MySQL database using root user not connecting. Showing this error:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could resolve this issue by creating another user through the following query:

```
create user '[USERNAME]'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by '[PASSWORD]';
```

I could understand Oracle has made default authentication type `caching_sha2_password` in MySQL-8. I found article here:

> In MySQL 5.7, the default authentication plugin is
>   mysql_native_password. As of MySQL 8.0, the default authentication
>   plugin is changed to caching_sha2_password.

Please find the complete article here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html

Another way to resolve this issue, we can alter the user by changing authentication type from default `caching_sha2_password` to `mysql_native_password`. This is the similar way to do:

[Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the "fancy" `caching_sha2_password` credential plugin, you may upgrade (if you are able) your SQLyog to 13.1.3 or later.
Quoted from [Version-History - 2019](https://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/193-version-history-2019) of SQLyog

> --The “caching_sha2_password” authentication plugin (default in recent MySQL 8 servers) is now supported.