# Pentaho PDI ETL : error connection to mysql version 8

Tags: mysql, pentaho-data-integration

It seems that there are issues with the newest MySQL version, I can connect to MySQL database using MySQL workbench, but when I try to connect via Pentaho PDI,
I get this error.

> > Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.

It seems that many people are having issues with current version of MySQL:

I have found this link below:
[Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Just wondering if anyone has encountered this issue with Pentaho PDI, and what are the possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, i read online that for MySQL 8 one really needs the JAR file : mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar, I was using like: mysql-connector-java-5.1.jar.

Comment: So I put into Pentaho lib directory where i replaced the old JAR file with the new one. Now its gives a different message, pentaho error message is that it could not find the JAR file for MySQL.

Comment: Seems like, Pentaho in version 8, has not updated things for MySQL version 8?