# Mysql with Homebrew - Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded:

Tags: mysql, installation, homebrew

Just installed a new version of mysql with homebrew. I am getting the following error.

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.

```
Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 50 seconds).

MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found
```

I did try and run

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: This seems to be a big problem with MySQL 8.0 that didn't exist in 5.7.

Comment: yes - they have increased the security, it kills all my sql clients (table plus & Sequel pro) but I can work with it via the command line.

Comment: Try to follow these steps in this post it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded?r=SearchResults&s=1|696.1149