# Can't connect to mysql docker image with MySql workbench

Tags: mysql, docker

I run the [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) with this command:

`docker run --name mysql-docker -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql_root -d mysql:8.0.12`

The container is running.  When I try to connect to it with MySQL Workbench from my local machine I get

`Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The documentation on the dockerhub page don't say anything about connecting from localhost, so I'm using 127.0.0.1 as the Hostname in MySQL Workbench.

How do I connect to MySQL running in a docker container from my local machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Comment: That link contained the work-around for this problem.  I ran into several other problems with MySQL just setting up a user and creating the first schema.  I can't believe that there are so many errors in a mature database.  Dropping MySQL and using Postgresql.