# I can't find the correct file in my xampp directory or method to fix my mysql config

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently downloaded Xampp and drupal so I can create a website with phpmyadmin, however, while playing around with the settings in phpmyadmin, I changed the user permissions just as a test, and since then I have been locked out of MySQL. the page I get everytime I run the local server has been shown below. 
Though this is a trivial mistake, I am still leaning and it isn't a pleasant experience already.

[mysqli error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAfNf.png)
Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks!
[[Xampp error log; MySQL error ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZB3m.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZB3m.png)

[xampp error log; MySQL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEUSi.png)

Comment: Well, it would be nice to know what changes you have made that resulted in this error.

Comment: All I remember is that i modified the user permissions on the phpmyadmin settings, and must have denied them by accident. It was over a month ago.

Comment: Nope, this is not an access denied error message. See the following answer, perhaps it can help you. Use the command line to alter the authentication plugin. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228443/5389997

Comment: Start CMD and run 'resetroot.bat' file with admin rights found in mysql folder in xampp. for eg. 'C:/xampp/mysql/resetroot.bat'. Comes built in with xampp for cases like these.

Comment: so now i'm getting these errors when I run mysql on xampp. the problem is that i have already deleted known instances of the mysql server and mysql workbench which was using the port on my pc. I'm not sure what else to do 
2018-10-02 13:46:23 2156 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
2018-10-02 13:46:23 2156 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2018-10-02 13:46:23 2156 [ERROR] Aborting