# How to fix Authentication method caching_sha2_password not supported by any of the available plugins in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

Authentication method `caching_sha2_password` not supported by any of the available plugins.
[image]

How can I fix this? or do I need to use another `SQL Server`?

I don't know what's the problem if it's the installation of `MySQL Server`
or just the code I'm using, I also added `MySQL.Data` on the reference still not working.

This is the code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class PIS

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=circuit; password=password; database=pis;"
    cn.Open()
    MsgBox("Connected")
    switchpanel(search)

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Did you try to search for the exact error message words? There are many links here and in external sites that explain the possible reasons for this message.

Comment: yes i tried to, there are suggestions to update mysql-connector, but when i updated it, it also gave me error that the framework is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating .NET FRAMEWORK target value to 4.5.2

Answer (score 2):

My reputation is too low to add as comment. Here a similar problem faced by other user.

[Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Comment: I tried those steps too, my workbench is working, the only problem is when i import MySql.Data.MySqlClient to the Visual Studio the syntax .Open() is not working and it shows the error above. Is it possible that my Visual Studio version is old that's why it caused the error?

Comment: what is your version of MySql Nuget package? You need to update the version 8.0.x or later.

Comment: i'm using the latest version of MySql Nuget package

Comment: i think the problem is that i'm using old versions of Visual Studio, and latest version of MySql Server, it does not support caching_sha2_password, any suggestions for a new SQL Server that's easy to use in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you have to update the mysql connector:

1. go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/
2. download mysql-installer-community-8.0.xx.xx.msi
3. run the msi file to update the connector
4. At Visual Studio > Solution Explorer > Reference, remove MySql.Data (old reference) and add the new one (version 8.0.xx)

Hope to help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a local Mysql server to test entity framework 6 database generation with code first. I got this error trying to add a new migration.

[image]

When setting up Mysql Server, you can choose two kind of authentification methods:

- Strong password encryption (new secure method)
- legacy anthentification method

Reconfiguring my server with Mysql Installer solved the problem for me using the **legacy anthentification method**. And I'm using .net framework 4.5.1.