# How to connect mysql docker container to node.js server or workbench

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

Iam beginner to docker and iam working on mysql and node.js I run mysql docker container as

```
docker run --name docker-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest
```

and result of docker ps is showing mysql container is running 
and docker logs says

**MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.**

how to connect with this container in workbench or in my application

[image: docker ps]

Comment: localhost:3306 or the port u mapped with host port. another option docker inspect db and find the container IP and contact with that IP

Comment: i find the container IP by "docker inspect container-name" it returns "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2" ... and many other properties..
i try to connect work bench with this ip and port 3306 but it didn't connect and stack for a minute and says failed to connected

Comment: if i write localhost as host name it connect to my default instance the old one that i use with xampp

Comment: make sure your port mapping is correct docker run -d --name consenter name -p 3306:3306 , in this case other application out side docker can see mysql

Comment: now i make a separate dir for this container file as mentioned 
at https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/ 
docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag

and use docker exec -it mysql bash and create a new user and grant all previllages now i connect this with workbench and it is now connected and showing a test database , but... it now its now creating new schema  as permission denied for use ''@localhost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name docker-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest
```

This will bind the port 3306 on your local machine to the docker image. You should be able to connect to the database with localhost & port 3306 with username `root` and password `abc123`.

I just tested it and it works like a charm.

[image]

---

If you are struggling with the error:

> failed to connect to localhost at 33016" details = Authentication
>   plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image
>   not found

**Update your MySQL-workbench.**

*If that doesn't work you will need to add a `native password` to the root user.* Here is how:

1. Connect to your docker image via bash:

   docker exec -it docker-mysql bash
2. Log into mysql as root

   mysql --user=root --password
3. Enter the password for root (Default is 'root', but 'abc123' in this example)
4. Finally Run:

   ALTER USER 'root' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'abc123';

Comment: when i use 3306:3306

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mysql (764873ef2b1633e3e20ae2ab91a4c45fbba5913ba3821c5d7795db3cc72ea44c): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated.

Comment: if u try other ports like 33512:3306   no docker process start 
docker ps show nothing

Comment: it try this by localhost and 3306 it connects successfully as you share screenshot but its showing my old connection databases which i used with xampp

Comment: Ok. That means something else is running on that port. Do you have any other MySQL servers running on that port, maybe an local instance? 

Anyhow, you can try to run the docker on a different port like this:

`docker run -p 3308:3306 --name docker-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest`

Comment: now i make a separate dir for this container file as mentioned at docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag

Comment: If you get your old stuff it means you are connecting to another mysql database. I would suggest:

1. Uninstall or at least stop the other mysql databse
OR
1. Use a different port for the docker mysql

Comment: now i type "docker run -p 33016:3306  --name mysql  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest" 

and process started and showing in "docker ps" with  containerID as well 

now i open workbench and try to connect with "localhost" , port:33016 user :root , password:abc123  fine..
now it says..  "failed to connect to localhost at 33016" 
details = Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found

Comment: That is a classic error :-) It means that your mysql workbench can't process the password. **Try updating your mysql workbench as it seems to have been a while.** Otherwise I would suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded

Comment: should i use -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql  or not

Comment: You don't need that. Your only issue now is the mysql version is different than your mysql workbench version :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188921/discussion-between-basit-raza-and-mr-turtle).

Comment: You were right @Mr Turtle i change mysql version to 5.7 which  my workbench version support and now it connect to container port. thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the port

Use `-p`, or `-P`

-p is bound to a custom port, -P will randomly assign a port to you.

`:latest` does not need to add, docker will help you add.

The final command should look like this:

```sh
docker run -dit -P --name docker-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 mysql:latest
```

Then use xx to see the exposed ports:

```sh
docker port docker-mysql
```

Check which port of the machine is mapped to port 3306 of the container, My result is:

```
33060/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32818
3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32819
```

Now you can connect to this port via software or code.

Comment: for what -dit flag is used for

Comment: docker run -dit -P --name docker-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 mysql:latest . doesn't start the docker process and nothing shows in docker ps

Comment: You try to use `docker ps -a` and `docker logs docker-mysql`

Comment: I think this article can help you: https://hackernoon.com/nodejs-mysql-install-setup-tutorial-example-connection-insert-query-fd5c5032d3b0

Answer (score 0):

For development best way is to connect the container to "host" network

```
docker run --name docker-mysql --network host -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest
```

When you will move to staging/prod environment consider to use some orchestration solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run docker inspect container_id its will show container port but will not show host port bind. By Default running without -p flag it will assign port to container but will not expose host port , so to achieve this you shout try -p flag, -p 3306:3306 in docker run command.