# TypeError: no salt specified in flask(about sha256)

Tags: python, flask, sha256

I am following a tutorial on `flask` from `Youtube` to build my own website. However, there is an error even though I followed every step as stated in the video.

My Operating System is `MacOS`, but the author of the video uses `Linux`.

Here is my relevant code:

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

class register_form(Form):
    username=StringField('Username',[validators.Length(min=2,max=30)])
    password=PasswordField('Password',[
        validators.Length(min=4,max=20),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm',message='Password do not match')
        ])
    confirm=PasswordField('Confirm Password')
    email=StringField('E-mail',[validators.Length(min=6,max=30)])

@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form_reg=register_form(request.form)
    if request.method=='POST' and form_reg.validate():
        username=form_reg.username.data
        email=form_reg.username.data
        password=sha256_crypt().encrypt(str(form_reg.password.data))
        #create cursor
        cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(username,email,password))
        #commit to db
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        flash('Register successfully,returning to home page...','success')
        #jump to home if success
        redirect(url_for('/home'))
        return render_template('register.html',user=userinfo)
    return render_template('register.html',form=form_reg,user=userinfo)
```

And attached is my screenshot regarding the error, hopefully it might be helpful:
[image]

Any ideas on what I can try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `passlib's` [documentation](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.1/password_hash_api.html#passlib.ifc.PasswordHash.encrypt) the `encrypt()` method takes a `secret` as a parameter and this **secret must be in either unicode or bytes**:

```
classmethod PasswordHash.encrypt(secret, **kwds)
```

**Parameters:**

**secret** (unicode or bytes) – string containing the password to encode.

If it **isn't in unicode or bytes** this method will throw a **TypeError** as you're seeing in your screenshot:

**TypeError:**

- if secret is not unicode or bytes.
- if a keyword argument had an incorrect type.
- if a required keyword was not provided.

You could *try encoding your password string into Unicode* before attempting to call the `encrypt()` method and seeing if this resolves your error. Something along the lines of:

```
password_utf=form_reg.password.data.encode()
password = sha256_crypt().encrypt(password_utf)
```

Alternatively, maybe you could try hashing your form password like the following instead:

```
# generate new salt, hash password

password = sha256_crypt.hash(form_reg.password.data))
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The first sol doesn't work and still shows the same error. for the second one, there is a new error:```Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded``` I found somebody faced the same dilemma with me on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded] I will try it, thanks

Comment: np best of luck!