# How to fix "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded" with mysql@5.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Database creation fails with `Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded` error.

Above error occurs when I run following command:

`$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create`

Error message:

```
Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.46/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>true, "pool"=>5, "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock", "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "database"=>"ht_test"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci
(if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

I know other developers had similar issues with mysql@8.* . Thats why I switched to `mysql@5.6` . Still I am facing this issue.

Please suggest possible solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

try using this, it worked for me

```
ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'youpassword';
```