# Reading Data from MySQL database into R

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I'm trying to use the RMySQL package to read data directly from tables in a MySQL database into R. However I can't make the connection to the DB from R.

The line of code:

```
mydb <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                  user = "root", 
                  password = "*****************************", 
                  dbname = "home", host = "")
```

returns the error message

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :    Failed to connect to database: Error:
>   Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module
>   could not be found.

Can anyone help here please?
Thanks

Comment: See this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded

Comment: Thank you. I read that and I followed the suggestion by Deepak rkm of adding a new user with "standard" password authentication and boom, I'm in