# The username of a manually installed MySQL

Tags: mysql, terminal

I have downloaded MySQL from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

I clicked on the file and installed it.

Now I have it in my Mac System Preferences > MySQL

I do not remember the username that I used (probably the default they gave me).

How can I know the username of MySQL?

(MacOS Catalina. 10.15.3. I use the Terminal)

Comment: Did you try root?

Comment: I tried. It gives me a long error. At the end:  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
sqlState: '08004',
fatal: true

Comment: that has nothing to do with the username, that is a problem that mysql doesn't by default allow this  see how you can change it to native password https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228443/5193536

Comment: I am a beginner. I just do not understand that answer

Comment: mysql 8 has increased security and doesn't allow plain passwords. so your user has to support native_password like described in the link provided, so alter the user like described and it works.

Comment: I am just beginning a tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp I just do not know where I have to put that code you mention

Comment: simpy connect to your server mysql -u root -p password and and enter then the commands

Answer (score 1):

The default username in mySql is root
Connect to the sql server using:
 mysql -u root

Comment: As I said to nbk: I tried. It gives me a long error. At the end: sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client', sqlState: '08004', fatal: true