# Why am I getting the error "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found."?

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm trying to run a Perl script that updates a MySQL database from a third party remote server. Everything works fine on my home PC however I've just moved my setup onto AWS and I'm now getting an error from this line:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:oncourt:127.0.0.1","root","root",{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 }) || die $DBI::errstr;
```

The error is:

```
DBI connect('oncourt:127.0.0.1','root',...) failed: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have had this error before when I moved machines and I solved it by adding a `.mylogin.cnf` file to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL`. However, this isn't working for me now - could it be anything to do with the fact that I'm now logged in as `Administrator` rather than a standard user?

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Use [legacy authentication mode](https://medium.com/@crmcmullen/how-to-run-mysql-8-0-with-native-password-authentication-502de5bac661).

Comment: Thanks. Have tried this before and again now and makes no difference. I updated ```my.ini``` to read ```default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password```. Was there anything else I should have done? I have restarted the AWS instance.

Comment: It's worth checking with `SHOW VARIABLES` to see if it stuck.

Comment: Might need a bit more info I'm afraid - relative newbie here. What is ```SHOW VARIABLES``` and what do I need to do with it?

Comment: That's a command you can use to find out the current configuration of the server. You may be editing a config file which has no impact on the running server, so you need to connect (e.g. via `mysql` command-line tool) and confirm it's applied correctly.

Comment: Figured out I can just run it as a query via Workbench :) So ```default_authentication_plugin``` is set to ```mysql_native_password``` and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I followed the command line solution here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/50209363/11277108. Everything is working ok. Thanks for trying to help @tadman!