# MySQL connector error: "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported"

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(

    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="henry123test",
    )
```

This was the error returned

> mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported.

Can anyone help me, been googling for some time now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Comment: This error is typical if you installed the deprecated `mysql-connector` and not `mysql-connector-python`.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for clarifying, I just installed mysql-connector-python and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

/////first uninstall by

```
            pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
```

////then install

```
            pip install mysql-connector-python
```

/////to check rather its working or not, some code in python

import mysql.connector as connector

try:

```
con = connector.connect(database='DATABASENAME', host='HOSTNAME', port='3306',
                    user='root', password= 'PASSWORD')

print(con)

print ("Cursor is found")
```

except:

```
print ("Cursor is not found") `
```

////// MORE CMD FOR SQL

sql command for show databases -> show databases;

sql command for use database -> use databaseNAME;

sql command for create -> ->   create database NAME;

sql command for status -> ->   status;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnOaL.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

usethis without end dot your problem wil be solved
pip3 install mysql-connector-python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67086525/18145256).

Answer (score -2):

You can try: `pip3 install mysql-connector-python`