# Docker mysql can log in from inside but cannot from outside

Tags: mysql, docker, access-denied

So i created a container of mysql like that

```
docker run --name mysqldb -v ~/Documents/docker/mysqldb:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=students -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass123 --rm -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

The thing is that when i try to connect with CLI i get Access denied. I run the command like that:

```
mysql -u user -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Then strange thing is that if i try to log in inside the container it's ok.

```
docker exec -it mysqldb bash
bash-4.2# mysql -u user -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 99
Server version: 8.0.22 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

So i don't know what is going on...

**UPDATE**
I followed Andrei Kovrov's answer and even tho it worked the last day, now i get this new error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE2**
i managed to solve the above error-1045 problem following these steps:

> I loged in the container
>
> docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash then log into mysql as root
>
> mysql --user=root --password Enter the password for root (Default is
> 'root') Finally Run:
>
> ALTER USER 'username' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY
> 'password';

and the answer came from this [github post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded). Ok it solved my problem but temporary cause whenever i drop the container and start it up again i face the same problem with that `ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password`. So it's a temporary solution but not final and correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u user -p`

From the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html)

```
Client programs determine what type of connection to make as follows:

If the host is not specified or is localhost, a connection to the local host occurs:

On Windows, the client connects using shared memory, if the server 
was started with the shared_memory system variable enabled 
to support shared-memory connections.

On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, 
in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other 
network-based programs: the client connects using a Unix socket file. 
The --socket option or the MYSQL_UNIX_PORT environment 
variable may be used to specify the socket name.
```

Comment: thanks it worked. Something strange is happening with sockets and tcp/ip if you don't specify the -h and -P

Comment: i get this error now even though yesterday worked: ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: It’s not related to the docker. Please create a separate question if you want to get answer. Moreover, now you’re using mariadb instead of mysql according your error.

Comment: yeah but that is strange. take in mind that i get this error executing mysql client...
i will leave few hours and then i will create a new one with the second question and of course i will accept your answer.