# SQL using method 'caching_sha2_password' error

Tags: sql, c, sha2

Hi there are 10 computers. Put the program on everything and connected them to the database server.
9 connected ok, but the tenth does not connect and pings the error:

Authentication to host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' for user 'xxx' using method 'caching_sha2_password'
failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed.

Tell me how to fix this?
The problem, as I understand it, is in the computer, since no error occurs on other PCs

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)