# Python mysql connection with ssl without password

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, passwords

I am trying to use my SSL certs to connect to the my sql from python `MySQLdb` module. I am doing like

```
Python 3.8.6 (default, Feb  4 2021, 21:45:23)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.12.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import MySQLdb
   ...: # Connect
   ...: db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.host.name",
   ...:                      user="username",
   ...:                      db="database",
   ...:                      ssl={"cert": "/var/lib/certs/mysql_prod.cert.pem",
   ...:                           "key": "/var/lib/keys/ui.key.pem"})
   ...:
   ...: cursor = db.cursor()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 3
      1 import MySQLdb
      2 # Connect
----> 3 db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.host.name",
      4                      user="username",
      5                      db="database",
      6                      ssl={"cert": "/var/lib/certs/mysql_prod.cert.pem",
      7                           "key": "/var/lib/keys/ui.key.pem"})
      9 cursor = db.cursor()

File /var/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py:123, in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
    120 """Factory function for connections.Connection."""
    121 from MySQLdb.connections import Connection
--> 123 return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

File /var/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py:185, in Connection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    182 # PEP-249 requires autocommit to be initially off
    183 autocommit = kwargs2.pop("autocommit", False)
--> 185 super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    186 self.cursorclass = cursorclass
    187 self.encoders = {k: v for k, v in conv.items() if type(k) is not int}

OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")
```

If I use same certs, with my `mysql` command, it works.

```
-bash-4.2$ sudo  mysql --ssl-mode=REQUIRED --ssl-cert=/var/lib/certs/mysql_prod.cert.pem --ssl-key=/var/lib/keys/ui.key.pem -u username -h mysql.host.name database
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 118485292
Server version: 8.0.32-24 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2009-2019 Percona LLC and/or its affiliates
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> exit
Bye
```

I tried passing `ssl_mode` in `MySQLdb.connect` but it gives error. `NotSupportedError: MySQL client library does not support ssl_mode specification`.

I also check the version of `mysqlclient`, its the latest one.

```
$ pip freeze | grep mysqlclient
mysqlclient==2.1.1
```

I am not sure, what is missing? the `ssl_mode` is compulsory to pass in python or I have to install which will add `/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so`.

I also check [Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded), but it suggest to change password, but we are able to login without password from `mysql` command, so I pass that option, second option its mention to update `my.cnf`, where I have to change that, in my client side or from my server side?