cygwin perl access to mysql 8.xx database not working
I have an upgraded install of a WAMP server that is now running MySQL 8.039 instead of MySQL 5.xx that seems to be working as expected for WAMP access.
Now, I am trying to give my cygwin perl scripts access to the database and that isn't going so well.

perl error: Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: No such file or directory
All searches lead to old (2018-2020) suggestions of reverting back to old password forms which is not acceptable.

Eventually found a recommendation of using DBD:MariaDB instead of DBD:MySQL. Claims DBD:mysql with MySQL 8 is "buggy."
Perl compile error:     *Can't locate DBD/MariaDB.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::MariaDB module) *

Tried cygwin setup install to get DBD:MariaDB.
That seems to just install DBM:mysql and calls it good. Didn't help anything.

Tried CPAN install of DBM:MariaDB.
a. That downloaded /DBD-MariaDB-1.23.tar.gz and then failed because it couldn't find mariadb_config or mysql_config.
b. Found https://metacpan.org/dist/DBD-MariaDB/view/lib/DBD/MariaDB/INSTALL.pod#Configuration
with directions for "Build MySQL clients under Cygwin" which sounded promising, with the following instructions:
 Download the MySQL LINUX source from https://www.mysql.com/downloads, unpack mysql-<version>.tar.gz into some tmp location and from this directory run configure:

 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --without-server

 .
 .
 .
 .

c. There is no "configure" in the tar file.


Everything I have found leads to dead-ends...
How do I get perl on cygwin to access my MySQL 8.xx database?

ad 4: mariadb_config is not configure. You probably need to install the devel package for mariadb.

That's not a perl error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded

I assume that reverting back to mysql_native_password would require down-grading the WAMP server and reduce security there. I would prefer not to do that. I find it hard to believe that after 6 years since that original suggestion there isn't a better answer for the perl interface to the database.

Thanks for comment about develop package for mariadb. I found two versions in cygwin setup (3.0.9-1 and 10.3.14-1, both unmaintained) and downloaded them. Then tried CPAN install DBD::MariaDB again, which seemed to work -- sortof. When I tried my perl script again; I am back to  square one, with "Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: No such file or directory" when trying to connect to the database.

I'd try removing the mariadb developer package and install one for mysql 8 and build the newest DBD::mysql from cpan.  I don't use mysql 8, so don't know for sure, but aiui all the password type issues are with old clients

alternatively, switch to mariadb for your server, though even there 10.3 is a very old version for the client, you'd want to find something newer

Ultimately, I created a mysql user specifically for perl access to the database and configured that user for mysql_native_password allowing access from localhost only. All other users are configured as caching_sha2_password.
