# How to run django web app with mysql in the same Docker? ERROR (docker-compose up -d seems to work ok)

Tags: python, django, docker

**Everything seems working fine:**
But I cannot access it on localhost:8000

'''
root@zenek:~/InternF# sudo docker-compose ps

### Name                   Command               State                 Ports

internf_app_1   sh -c python manage.py run ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
internf_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
'''

I get this error after after trying to migrate. I got similar error using postgres db as well

'''

```
root@zenek:~/InternF# sudo docker-compose run app python manage.py migrate
Starting internf_db_1 ... done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, 'Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, 'Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')
```

'''

I am using:

'''

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mysql'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

'''

and Dockerfile

'''

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFER 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app
```

'''

HELP!

Comment: "In the same Docker"—this is an antipattern. Each service should have its own container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not able to connect to mysql docker from local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019652/not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-docker-from-local)

Comment: It looks like your Django is just misconfigured. What's your `DATABASES` setting?

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50070699/5921826
also it is described in official mysql docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql scroll to `docker-compose` part

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}

Comment: have you solved the issue yet?