# In docker or docker-compose set the mysql8.0 password type to be mysql_native_password

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker or docker-compose, how to set the mysql8.0 password type to be mysql_native_password.
I run the below query after I run the docker container, but I want it auto change when I create the container.

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
ALTER USER 'default'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'secret';
```

Comment: Are you using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/8.0/images/sha256-44f98f4dd825a945d2a6a4b7b2f14127b5d07c5aaa07d9d232c2b58936fb76dc?context=explore)?

Comment: This seems to be an old answer, so I don't know if it still works, but have you tried this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021165/3181933

Comment: [grajnish/mysql8.0.22](https://hub.docker.com/r/grajnish/mysql8.0.22) I using this one. @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: Does that image provide anything that the official docker image doesn't? You'll probably have a better time finding answers using the official image. Also, when you say _"I run the below query after I run the docker container"_ - can I take that to mean that you're running this automatically as another Docker step? Or is this something you're doing entirely manually?